# JSONLOADER in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i used JSONloader to load the model in three.js,it work fine, the only problem that am having is steps or even documentation that will help me to preload the textures(which are images) so that i create an interaction(switch images with mouse click).

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
    callbackKey = function(geometry,materials) {createScene(geometry,materials,0, 0, 0, 25)};
    loader.load("3dmodel/Converse_obj/converse_obj.js", callbackKey);

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);


}


function createScene(geometry,materials, x, y, z, scale) {

    zmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    zmesh.position.set(x, y, z);
    zmesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
    meshes.push(zmesh);
    scene.add(zmesh);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to tackle this problem, and it may not have much to do with three.js.

Three does come with a [LoadingManager](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/loaders/LoadingManager.js) class, i believe it's something like this:

```
function onAllMyTexturesLoaded () {...}
function onSingleTextureLoaded() {...}
myTextureManager = new THREE.LoadingManager( onAllMyTexturesLoaded , onSingleTextureLoaded , onError )

myTextureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader( myTextureManager )
```

You can start loading your mesh once all the textures are loaded. Anything you load via this loader should fire those callbacks.

You could also put texture id's in a dictionary, flag them true when they come in, iterate through keys and see if they are all true, fire an event.